# Web-based OLAP CUBE browser?

Tags: web-apps, sql-server, business-intelligence

I have cube on MS SQL Server and I want to install a web based visual client tool for exploring and analyzing OLAP databases.
A cube is an array of data understood in terms of its 0 or more dimensions.
That web-based app should support:

- data exploration/auditing
- generation of reports
- generation of embeddable charts/graphs

Comment: Did anybody use pivot4J?

Answer (score 4):

I have used and recommend [Saiku](http://www.meteorite.bi/saiku).

It is a Pentaho plugin, you have to install it from Marketplace after you have installed and launched the Pentaho BI server.

Saiku allows you to explore and drill down data with a nicer interface than Pentaho's default.

It also allows you to quickly create graphs:

[image]

To create more advanced reports/dashboards, Saiku also allows you to get the MDX for the current exploration, which you can then use with the "Community Dashboard Editor" plugin.

Comment: Thank @Nicolas Raoul, could I access to the "mssql CUBE" which it was created by someone else and I want just to use it and analyse its data ? In other hand could I use third party CUBE on that ?

Comment: Yes, you can use MSSQL data as well. I believe that any cube is OK as long as it is written in standard MDX.

Comment: Hey @nicolas-raol, I installed Saiku and connected it to SSAS after so many challenging, now do you know can I display Saku server chart in other 3th party web application? I just want to display our created chart on some web pages (.jsf)

Comment: @soheilz92: Yes, open your chart, go to the MDX dialog, copy/paste, then use this MDX in your third-party application.

Comment: @nicolas-raol :No, I mean only displaying a chart on other web pages, some thing like I user saiku taglibs and send some request to saiku server and it response a respected chart.

Comment: I see! I have not tried, but I am pretty sure you can do it yes! You should ask this as a new question at http://stackoverflow.com (be sure to include version details and all other details)

Answer (score 2):

Actually there are a lot of apps with some similar features and with some differences. I'd made a short presentation for inner clients during my work to choose an app for us. As a user of BI, not a developer, I looked at app from simple point of view. I wish it works fine, do what I need for the cost we can pay.  As i understood there is no full web-analog to exel which works fast with different types of cubes, has same or very close features and can be easily configured.

Your  choice depends on how you want to use it, what is cost limitations and what is more important for you (work with bid ammounts of data, concrete visualisation features, easy configuration..) and what plans do you have for this app, can their support make a custom project for you etc.

**Webpivotable** costs not much, works fine, but their design may be better, but thats just for me. [Here their demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo/).

[**icCube**](http://www.icCube.com) - nice team, support, tool totally for OLAP and their webreporting tool is enough for some usual needs, but not more. Regarding futher detailisation, this is not for you.

[**Flexmonster**](http://www.flexmonster.com/Demo/flash-pivot-table-component-demo-load-msolap) - looks nice, works good, professional team and possible different types of customization, but quite costly.

**Dundas** is really not bad too, actually. You need to sign in to get their demo.

If you tell me more about your needs I'd try to be more specific. These apps were the first ones I remembered.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my organization (insurance company), their looking for open source (java based preferred ) app, to work with pre-created cube in SSAS, they asked me to find a web application for top-level manager for analytic issues.

Comment: Than, let me think.. really saiku or jpivot, both open source and java.
https://github.com/rjackson/pivot.js - open source too but written on coffescript.  Good luck in your search!

Answer (score 1):

What I have found till now is Pentaho.
The open source BI tool which has tow servers (BA Server and Data Integration Server) and several tools.
It has web console to touch it with web browser, but the tools are windows application. 
The other thing I have found is Pentaho has its own Cube Designer and you should design your Cube with that in order to analyze it in data analyzer web application.

Comment: I installed Saiku and connected it to SSAS, it works fin :) other tasks are coming to me to do with Cube viewer :D

Answer (score 1):

I have conducted a trial of Kyubit and it is a very good portal for OLAP dashboards. They have an aggressive release cadence with frequent improvements to their functionality. For a small to midsize business or department using Analysis Services, this is an excellent option.

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion [Olap Client](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejolapclient) allows for connecting to SSAS and analyzing cubes. There is a free [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) available.

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Answer (score 0):

Best web based OLAP browser and much more is our product 'Kyubit Business Intelligence'. You're gonna love it on first sight.

[www.kyubit.com](http://www.kyubit.com)

[image]

Comment: If you plug your own product, at least be honest enough to say so in the text.

Answer (score 0):

As for 2019 there are several new alternatives in addition to the already mentioned in prev answers:

- [PivotData microservice](https://www.nrecosite.com/pivotdata_service.aspx) if you're looking for something that can be is seamlessly integrated into existing web application. Can connect *directly* to SQL-compatible databases including OLAP DBs like BigQuery, Redshift, ClickHouse. Connector to OLAP cubes (XMLA client) was added recently. Unlike many other solutions you can specify custom MDX templates.
- [SeekTable](https://www.seektable.com/) which is a standalone web-based BI tool, has both cloud and on-premise versions (can be used **for free**, only advanced functions require a subscription). With 'publish to web' functionality reports may be embedded into any other webapps with IFRAMEs. SeekTable uses PivotData microservice under the hood, so support of data sources is exactly the same.

Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with these products.